# /boot file system cannot be of type btrfs subvolume

Tags: fedora, btrfs

I am trying to install Fedora 27 along with Windows 10. Created the bootable flash drive using Rufus in "GPT partition scheme for UEFI" mode. I allocated a `/boot/efi` and `/`. But I can not proceed. There is an error:

```
/boot file system cannot be of type btrfs subvolume
```

[image]

Comment: Why post image's when the error is already in text above?

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/boot must be a file system that the GRUB bootloader supports. Btrfs is not one of them.

While your root can be Btrfs you would also need another partition at /boot that GRUB supports such as EXT4.

Sources: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f26/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda.html#sect-installation-gui-manual-partitioning-recommended

Comment: `/boot/efi` is in ext4 format. As I am in EFI mode do I need to create separate partition for `/boot`?

Comment: Yes. You need three partitions here. /boot/efi should be FAT for your UEFI. /boot should be anything GRUB supports. That includes FAT but I recommend using EXT4. Then you can make your root Btrfs.

Comment: Note that the error you are getting is related to GRUB and thats what I am referring to in my answer.

Comment: GRUB does support Btrfs, at least according to [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Btrfs#GRUB).

Comment: +Fox As far as Fedora is concerned it doesn't. It might be more accurate to say in my answer that Fedora doesn't support that configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: not a Fedora person. Arch Linux (what I use) recommends that the EFI System Partition (ESP) be mounted directly at `/boot`. In any case, the error is correct. The ESP needs to be FAT of some sort (generally VFAT).

If you are using a graphical program to partition your disk, it probably gives you a way to select the filesystem type. If you are using the command line, `mkfs.vfat` (or possibly `mkfs.msdos`) is what you want.

If you are dual-booting and have already installed another system in EFI mode, you *do not* want to overwrite (or reformat) the ESP. Simply reuse the existing one.

---

Edit: I see in your screenshot both a 512MB `/boot/EFI` and (in the "Unknown" section) `EFI System Partition`. This will not work. You will need to use (and not format) the existing ESP.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

`UEFI` needs an `ESP` partition.

The `ESP` partition needs to be formatted with a `FAT` based file system.

---

The `EFI` system partition (`ESP`) is a partition on a data storage device that is used by computers that boot using the Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (`UEFI`).

When a computer is booted, `UEFI` firmware loads files stored on the `ESP` to start installed operating system's.

An `ESP` needs to be formatted with a `FAT` based file system as part of the `UEFI` specification, If that is not done, you will not be able to boot into your newly installed OS.

---

The solution to your problem would be to create `/boot` and `/` partition's.

Format the `/boot` and `/` partition to `ext4` and use the already created `ESP` partition by window's. The installation should run successfully after.